# What needs to be taken care in Oracle 9i database when migrating from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2012?

Tags: database-migration, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012, oracle9i, windows-server-2012-r2

Currently Oracle 9i database is hosted on Windows server 2003. We are migrating Windows 2003 to Windows Server 2012. 
Here are two questions: 
a) Oracle 9i is compatible with windows server 2012? 
b) if not compatible with windows 2012, then what all things we need to take care?

Comment: [Looks like you'll need to upgrade to at least Oracle 11gR2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/tech-info/sod-oracle-db-win8-win2012-1853201.pdf), though as that is about to go out of support, you should be looking at 12c anyway.

Comment: is there no way that Oracle 9i can be run on Windows Server 2012?

Comment: It isn't certified. It may be possible to run it but it won't be supported (not that 9i has been supported for a long, long time anyway) and you may hit all sorts of problems. Why wouldn't you want to upgrade to a supported version of the database?

Comment: Thanks Alex. We were just figuring out if things can be worked without much changes. One more ques - if we upgrade from 9i to 12c, what all things should be taken care? any changes needs to be made in the exiting database?

Comment: That's off-topic and way too broad. There's no direct upgrade path from 9i to 12c (see [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/upgrade/upgrading-oracle-database-wp-12c-1896123.pdf)). You [could go to 11g](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/manageability/9i-to-11g-real-world-customer-exper-133754.pdf) but that's also out of support; it could potentially be a stepping stone to 12c. It may be easier to create a new 12c DB environment and migrate the data.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Will try for 12c.!! Thanks for your quick reply.